# Find the derivative of the function $(y^2-1)^2/(y^2+1)$

Tags: derivatives

How do I solve this? I tried using the quotient and the chain rule but I can't seem to get the correct answer.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Could you show us your steps so that we can identify your error?

Comment: derivative with respect to what? $y$?$x$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set $\;f(y)=\dfrac{(y^2-1)^2}{y^2+1}$ and use *logarithmic differentiation*:
\begin{align}
\frac{f'(y)}{f(y)}&=2\,\frac{(y^2-1)'}{y^2-1}-\frac{(y^2+1)'}{y2+1}=2\,\frac{2y}{y^2-1}-\frac{2y}{y^2+1}=2y\biggl(\frac{2}{y^2-1}-\frac{1}{y^2+1}\biggr)=\frac{2y(y^2+5)}{(y^2-1)(y^2+1)}
\end{align}
whence
$$ f'(y)=\frac{f'(y)}{f(y)}\,f(y)=\frac{2y(y^2+5)(y^2-1)}{(y^2+1)^2}. $$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

You can simplify the chain rule using $$(y^2-1)^2=\{(y^2+1)-2\}^2=?$$

Comment: Won't some of the remaining terms still need chain rule? (although simpler)

Comment: @GoodDeeds, Agreed

Answer (score 0):

Let:
$$p=(y^2-1)^2\to p'=2(2y)(y^2-1)=4y(y^2-1) \text{ [chain rule]}$$
$$q=y^2+1 \to q'=2y \text{ [implicit]}$$
Then the quotient rule:
$$\bigg(\frac pq\bigg)'=\frac{p'q-q'p}{q^2}$$
See if you can take this forward

Comment: I can't simplify it, I get confused on what to do next when I substitute the value of p, q, p' and q' in the quotient rule

Comment: Plugging in the values we get: $$\bigg(\frac{(y^2-1)^2}{y^2+1}\bigg)'=\frac{4y(y^2-1)(y^2+1)-2y(y^2-1)^2}{(y^2+1)^2}$$ You can then take out common factors for $$\frac{2y(y^2-1)[2(y^2+1)-(y^2-1)]}{(y^2+1)^2}$$ Go from there.